# In giblab-ci.yaml does `service` on a job spawn separate instances given the same `alias`?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

If I have two jobs in `gitlab-ci.yaml` with the service same alias, does GitLab start a single shared instance or two separate instances?

```
front_end_tests:
  image: docker:image
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: ${BRANCH_CONTAINER_IMAGE}
      alias: local-service-a

admin_tests:
  image: docker:image
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: ${BRANCH_CONTAINER_IMAGE}
      alias: local-service-b
```

Answer (score 1):

Each job is independant by default and so the images of your build and your services will be redownloaded each time to create new containers.

Note that this supposes you are using the default Docker in Docker (dind) executor. Shell or Kubernetes executors can behave differently.

Also, Gitlab CI provides caching mechanics, that avoid redownloading the same image several times for instance.

Check the [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) for more information.

Services aliases are used to creates several containers from the same image inside a job. They are limited to the scope of one job. For exemple, your app is using two mysql instances with different database. You'll need aliases to avoid name conflicts, see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#starting-multiple-services-from-the-same-image).

Comment: The jobs from the example are in the same stage, so will they share an instance of the service?

Comment: Ok I made a mistake and wrote stage instead of job. Jobs are independent and services are limited to the scope of one job. If they were not, jobs could not be paralleled. So no they won't share the service instance.